# Cycle through multiple lists with enumerate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I'm currently assigning each person in a list to a specific week of the month.  This is done for the the entire year.

```
import itertools
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
today_str = str(today)
year,month,date = today_str.split('-')
# convert week of the year to a number
current_week = (datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(date)).isocalendar()[1])

name_list1 = ["Kacey", "Cindy", "John"]

for num, item in enumerate(itertools.cycle(name_list1), 7):
    if num >= current_week:
        print(item)
        break
```

The above will find the person that falls on the 7th week.... Kacey

```
1. Kacey
2. Cindy
3. John
4. Kacey
5. Cindy
6. John
7. Kacey
```

How can I do this with 2 lists of names?  So each name in list1 will be assigned a week and each name in list2 will be assigned a week?  They are totally independent of each other.  I'm wanting to do this in one for loop if possible.

```
name_list1 = ["Kacey", "Cindy", "John"]
name_list2 = ["Bob", "Julie", "Brian"]
```

In list2, Bob would be #7.

```
1. Bob
2. Julie
3. Brian
4. Bob
5. Julie
6. Brian
7. Bob
```

I could create a for loop for each list, but that will get rather ugly when dealing with multiple lists.

Comment: `itertools.cycle(name_list1 + name_list2)`?

Comment: I think you are looking for [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to zip it:

```
for num, (item1, item2) in enumerate(itertools.cycle(zip(name_list1, name_list2)), 7):
    if num >= current_week:
        print(item1 + " " + item2)
        break
```